# Django Textfield maximum size to be displayed

Tags: django

I am using TextField in my models and I understand it has no limit of the size and I am happy with it. However is there is a way that not all the data of text field will be displayed in my template?

Let say I just want to display first 100 characters and the rest will be expended if I click link at the end like more or ....

Is there is something built in in Django framework or I have to do my own implementation?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it in template with filter : 
[truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)

```
{{ value|truncatechars:9 }}
```

> If value is "Joel is a slug", the output will be "Joel i...".

However this won't expand when you hover or click. For that you need CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis;` (see this : https://jsfiddle.net/438sm8ed/)

```
.hide-partially {
  width:75px;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.hide-partially:hover {
  overflow:visible;
}
```